# Find index of first digit in string

Tags: apple-numbers

How can I find the index of the first number in a string? For example, if I have a cell with "ABC099", the function should return 3.

I found this for excel but ISNUMBER is not an apple-numbers function.

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=0,0,MIN(IF(1*ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),1)),ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)+1)))*OR(ISNUMBER(1*LEFT(A1,1)),ISNUMBER(1*RIGHT(A1,1)))
```

Source:http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringformulas.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple if you want to use REGEX for it in any programing language.

Comment: How do I use regex in Apple numbers?